# Running multiple queries that begin by the same word in Access 2007 through VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am more or less a rookie in using VBA in Access and hope I'm not asking something stupid. Is it possible through VBA to run and save several queries that begin by the same word?

I have an Access file with multiple tables and queries, which are identified by an initial 3 digit code, eg 100QueryName. I am trying to only run the queries that begin with "901".

Hope someone can help me out.

Best regards

Jorge

Comment: I assume the queries are either to update/add records or are they to return a list to the user? And how many may be run at a time?

Answer (score 1):

The following code is a start (depending on what type of queries)...

Create a module and paste the following code. Then execute subroutine 'Test_it'

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit


Sub Test_it()
Dim strPrefix As String
    ' Ask user for query prefix
    strPrefix = InputBox("Please enter query prefix", "Qry Prefix")
    MsgBox "Executed " & Run_Queries(strPrefix) & " queries.", vbOKOnly, "COunt of Queries"
End Sub

Function Run_Queries(strPrefix As String) As Integer
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim strQryName  As String
Dim iQryCt      As Integer
Dim iQryRan     As Integer
Dim i           As Integer

    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    iQryCt = dbs.QueryDefs.Count
    i = Len(strPrefix)
    iQryRan = 0

    For Each qdf In dbs.QueryDefs
        strQryName = qdf.Name
        Debug.Print strQryName
        If LCase(left(strQryName, i)) = LCase(strPrefix) Then
            Debug.Print "    ** Run: " & strQryName & vbTab & qdf.Type
            If qdf.Type = 0 Then                ' Select query
                ' Open this query to view results
                DoCmd.OpenQuery strQryName
            ElseIf qdf.Type = 48 Then           ' Update query
                dbs.Execute strQryName
            End If
            iQryRan = iQryRan + 1
        Else

        End If
    Next qdf
    Set qdf = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing
    Run_Queries = iQryRan
End Function
```

Comment: Hello Wayne. I have tried this code and it appears to be working perfectly. Thank you for that. Just one question: when the queries are run this way are they automatically saved or is there a specific line of code that saves the query result? In addition, after running the code all queries are opened. Is it possible to add a command to close them all?

Comment: You never mentioned if they are action queries (perform table updates, append records, make table) or if they return a list of records. If they are action queries, then there will be no open lists, therefore I assume your question is about saving the results of a query that returns rows? Yes, you can close the query via the same code (i.e. DoCmd.Close acQuery, strQryName). However, you must want someone to be able to view the result before closing?

Comment: Sorry for not answering about the type of queries we are talking about. Half of them are select queries and half are append queries. Does that change anything?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to interface with the open query, then close it. Automatically closing the query is simple (just add 'DoCmd.Close acQuery, strQryName'). However, an interface requires a process that is a little more complicated. You can't simply add VBA code that prompts with a msgbox to close because that locks the process while the msgbox is open. One solution would be to create a form with a text box to search for prefix, command buttons to 'Run' and 'Close'. Each time you click 'Run' it would process next query; each 'Close' would close most recently opened. Else user could close...